# Cannot restore Kies backup after firmware upgrade

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, samsung-kies, restore

I backed up my Samsung Galaxy S2 on Kies before updating to Ice Cream Sandwich. After the upgrade I tried to restore, but the restore fails each time I try.

Comment: Does it provide you with any kind of specific error message when it fails?

Comment: I am having the same problem, the error message is not detailed; it just says the restore failed.
I have tried just selecting contacts rather than the full range of backed-up items but it has the same failure. Hoping there is a work-around before i resort to doing it all manually.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem; this is what worked for me:

- from the phone clear the app cache (I used app2sd)
- restart phone
- restart computer
- start Kies
- connect phone to computer
- run restore again

Done.

Answer (score 1):

1. Disable usb debugging in `settings` -> `applications` -> `development`.
2. Select samsung kies in `settings` -> `wireless` and `network` -> `usb settings`.
3. Try connecting the device again.